# Sublime Text 2 strip next whitespace character

Tags: character, sublimetext2, whitespace, multiple-select

I use sublime text as my favorite editor.

Is there a short-cut to remove the next whitespace characters?

Example: I am using (ctrl+d) to select all leading xml tags. This works fine.

```
<tag>   myText</tag>
<tag>anotherText</tag>
<tag>   \t myText</tag>
<tag>  yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Cursor (|) is now like follows:

```
<tag>|   myText</tag>
<tag>|anotherText</tag>
<tag>|   \t myText</tag>
<tag>|  yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Now I would like to remove the whitespaces to have for example the following result:

```
<tag> myText</tag>
<tag> anotherText</tag>
<tag> myText</tag>
<tag> yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Any solution for this?

Edit: Ctrl-right Ctrl-left gives me the following:

```
<tag>   |myText</tag>
<tag>|anotherText</tag>
<tag>   \t |myText</tag>
<tag>  |yetAnotherText</tag>
```

But I have not found a way yet to delete the (now preceding) white spaces.
I change my question to: strip next whitespace characters

Thank you and best regards
Samson

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution....

```
<tag>|   myText</tag>
<tag>|anotherText</tag>
<tag>|   \t myText</tag>
<tag>|  yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Ctrl-right:

```
<tag>   myText|</tag>
<tag>anotherText|</tag>
<tag>   \t myText|</tag>
<tag>  yetAnotherText|</tag>
```

Ctrl-left:

```
<tag>   |myText</tag>
<tag>|anotherText</tag>
<tag>   \t |myText</tag>
<tag>  |yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Ctrl-Shift-left: 
        **_**                <<<< selections
       |myText
         
    **|anotherText
        *_*___** 
       \t |myText
         
      |yetAnotherText

Shift-right:
         **_**
    |   |myText

```
<tag>|anotherText</tag>
     ________ 
<tag>|   \t |myText</tag>
     ____ 
<tag>|  |yetAnotherText</tag>
```

Finally I can delete the selected spaces ....